# Database query in android

Tags: android, database

In my application i have to retrieve data from database to display in a listview.My requirement is i have to retrieve data from database with "groups" as household and "category" as income.

My query is as follows:

```
public Cursor gethouseholdTitle(String  grps) throws SQLException
{
Cursor mCursor =
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] 
{
KEY_ROWID,
KEY_INCOME,
KEY_DESC,
KEY_QUANTITY,
KEY_TOTAL,
KEY_CATEGORY,
KEY_RECURR,
KEY_DATE,
KEY_GROUP
//KEY_PUBLISHER
},
KEY_GROUP + "=" + grps,
KEY_CATEGORY + "=" + "'Income'",
null,
null,
null,
null,
null
);
if (mCursor != null) {
mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
return mCursor;
}
```

But it shows error:

```
The method query(boolean, String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String, String) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (boolean, String, String[], 
 String, String, null, null, null, null, null).
```

As i new to this,please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logic, seems like you need to change

```
    KEY_GROUP + "=" + grps, KEY_CATEGORY + "=" + "'Income'",
```

to

```
    KEY_GROUP + "=" + grps + " and " + KEY_CATEGORY + "=" + "'Income'",
```

Hope this helps...